# Should I run a "sync" command before measuring the exact IO times?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sync, operating-systems

I am testing my new algorithm on a disk-based process. For comparison purposes, it is essential to measure the exact time that each [massive] read/write operation has taken.

It seems that on my Linux VM with a local HDD, the actual disk-write operations are still ongoing/pending even after the flush() is done (e.g. `BufferedWriter.flush()` in java). This conclusion is made by the evidence that:

1. When I run `sync ; sleep 60 ; sync`, the second `sync` is done on a blink.
2. When I run `sync ; ./myProg ; sync`, the second sync takes ***40 seconds***.

Why does the second sync takes so much time? I thought that the OS should guarantee the consistency when the program flushes data into file, but it does not seem to be true here. Why does Linux do such a risky buffering on a volatile memory?

Is it rational to include the time for the sync as a part of actual write time? (in my research paper)?

Answer (score 1):

You confuse `fflush()` with the various flavours of `fsync()`.

`fflush()` makes sure, that whatever is buffered inside your file handling stack is passed to the OS for writing it out.

`fsync()` makes sure, that the OS writes the data out to stable storage.

Comment: I don't use C. In java, the only thing you can do to flush a  `BufferedReader` object is to call the`flush()` or `close()` functions. This is supposed to make sure that the file is written on disk when the `bufferedReader.flush()` is called, but it is not.  As I know, there is no such functionalities in java.

Comment: I assume you mean a `bufferedWriter`. On this, `.flush()` does exactly what it says: It flushes the buffers of the Writer, claiming nothing about the underlying file. IIRC, you need to look into `bufferedWriter.getFD().sync()`

Comment: Correct! I applied a further getFD().sync() and it solved the issue. Note that for [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) does not provide access to the underlying file descriptor, i.e.   `bufferedWriter.getFD()` does not exist. Instead, we can use [BufferedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) which already has `bufferedOutputStream.getFD().sync()`